# How to loop through a web table column and download multiple PDF files using Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automationanywhere

I have an HTML table that has seven columns and 3 rows (the number of rows may be more or less). The second columns contains a links to  PDF files and the seventh column contains the phrase "Corrective Action" I only want to download the PDF files from the columns that contain the word "Corrective Action". However, my code is only downloading the first PDF.

Here is the code:
http://dev.atriumfinehomes.com/clonewebtable/sample.PNG

This is the table:
http://dev.atriumfinehomes.com/clonewebtable/table.htm

Could I get some help with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the links of the PDF files using Extract Table command.

**Steps to get the links:**
- Edit the Extract Table command -> Advanced view -> Step 6: Extract Selected Tag details to CSV file. Tag Name: Hyperlink, Attribute Name: Get URL.
- Save the data to another CSV file. (You can't save it in the same file as it will append or overwrite).
- Open the file CSV file as a spreadsheet.

[image: Extract Table Command]

**Inside the loop**
- Create a new variable **$vCounter$**, because the links.csv file dosn't conation headers as the table.
- Using variable operation assign **$Counter$-1** to **$vCounter$**.
- Using Get Cells command and get cell **A$vCounter$** and assign it to a new variable **$vPDFURL$**.
- Use **$vPDFURL$** as Download file URL in the download command.

[image: Taskbot command for more clarification]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you only download the 'correctiveaction1.pdf' but the PDF from the line 3 is named 'correctiveaction3.pdf'